# Delete item from observable collection in wp8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, observablecollection

I have an observable collection linked to a LongListItemSelector and this parts works fine.

I use the checkbox selection method, which builds a list in the background and this list is passed as a parameter when I click on my Delete button. In the Delete button method defined in my ViewModel, I have the following code:

```
foreach (FavoriteItemViewModel item in selectedFavorites)
{
    FavoriteItemViewModel itemToDeleted = this.Favorites
        .FirstOrDefault<FavoriteItemViewModel>(m =>
            m.Description.ToLowerInvariant() == item.Description.ToLowerInvariant());
    if (itemToDeleted != null)
        this.Favorites.Remove(itemToDeleted);
}
```

Where `selectedFavorites` is of type `List<Object>` and contains the items selected via a checkbox.

Each of the "object" is of type `FavoriteItemViewModel`. As the "object" contained in the list are slightly different from the one contained in my Favorites ObservableCollection, I make sure to first find the item in Favorites based on their Description as this should match.

If found, I delete it but I can this that the item is not actually being removed from `Favorites` observable collection.

I understand you cannot use a For Each to loop through an observable collection and try to remove an item directly, but I'm not doing that.

I've tried different scenarios but getting nowhere with it.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know it's not removed?  Check the return value of `Remove`, it'll be `true` if the item was removed.  Nothing leaps out as wrong in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

As issue is resolved only thing which could be done is to use removeall linq instead of other list.

```
Favorites.RemoveAll(a => selectedFavorites.Exists(w => ((FavoriteItemViewModel)w).Description == a.Description));
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem... Couple of mistake on my part!

First problem: How my property Favorites was defined:

```
    public ObservableCollection<FavoriteItemViewModel> Favorites
    {
        get
        {
            return _favorites ?? (this.LoadFavorites(App.MainViewModel.Favorites));
        }
        set
        {
            _favorites = value;
        }
    }
```

The `get` part never actually set the internal variable, thus reloading the data over and over again from the Favorites collection held in my MainViewModel.

I changed it from:

```
return _favorites ?? (this.LoadFavorites(App.MainViewModel.Favorites));
```

to

```
return _favorites ?? (_favorites = this.LoadFavorites(App.MainViewModel.Favorites));
```

Doooh!!

The second problem:

So while the following is not directly removing the object from my observable collection

```
private void DeleteAction(object actionParameter)
{
    List<object> selectedFavorites = actionParameter as List<object>;

    foreach (FavoriteItemViewModel item in selectedFavorites)
    {
        FavoriteItemViewModel itemToDelete = 
        this.Favorites.FirstOrDefault<FavoriteItemViewModel>
        (m => m.Description.ToLowerInvariant() == item.Description.ToLowerInvariant());

        if (itemToDelete != null)
          this.Favorites.Remove(itemToDelete);
   }
 }
```

The parameter `actionParameter` passed via the CommandParameter i.e. List, is the List of selected objects from my LongListSelector (Custom one to handle MVVM). This List is directly affected whenever an item is selected or unselected.

I assumed that this parameter would have been passed by value but this doesn't appear to be the case and is in fact passed by reference.

So calling

```
this.Favorites.Remove(itemToDelete)
```

does not work either as the second I remove it from the observable collection, it also affect the local variable `selectedFavorites` list which was assigned the actionParameter variable and I get the typical error:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in 
mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Collection was modified; enumeration 
operation may not execute.`
```

If I use a `for` loop, while I don't get the error, assuming that I have 2 items selected, the second I remove the first item from the Favorites observable collection, selectedFavorites.count drops from 2 to 1 and causes my `for` loop to finish too early.

So the only work around was to first build a separate list based on the `selectedFavorites` list then simply use a `for each` loop.

The final code looks like this:

```
    private void DeleteAction(object actionParameter)
    {
        List<object> selectedFavorites = actionParameter as List<object>;
        List<FavoriteItemViewModel> myList = new List<FavoriteItemViewModel>();

        Favorites.RemoveAll(a => selectedFavorites.Exists(w =>     ((FavoriteItemViewModel)w).Description == a.Description));

        myList = null;
    }
```

And this works as expected!

Comment: No need to build that list. You can simply have a for (int i = 0; i < actionParameter.Count();) {/**/} and inside its block you always Remove only the 0'th element.

Comment: Never thought of that! Thanks. I'll update the answer tomorrow when in front of pc!

Answer (score 0):

You can use prameterized constructor of `List<T>` to construct new `List` containing items from existing `List` without manual `foreach` loop. Something like this should be enough :

```
private void DeleteAction(object actionParameter)
{
    List<object> selectedFavorites = 
                    new List<object>(actionParameter as List<object>);
    foreach (var item in selectedFavorites)
    {
        this.Favorites.Remove((FavoriteItemViewModel)item);
    }
}
```

Normally We wouldn't need to call `Clear()` and set `selectedFavorites` to `null` because the variable it self declared in local context, so it will be qualified for garbage-collection soon after the method execution finished.